# Hover transition on clip path change

Tags: css, css-transitions, clip-path

With this code ,the hover effect is working ,the bottom right corner disappears but there is no transition,it's something wrong?

```
.mydiv:hover{
      background-color: blue;
      clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 80% 100%, 0% 100%);
      transition: 0.5s ease;
 }
```

Comment: try adding transition to `.mydiv`

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha it's doesn't work

Answer (score 8):

You need to add an initial `clip-path` definition to have a transition between two states:

```css
.box {
  background-color: blue;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  height:150px;
}

.box:hover {
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 80% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

You can also do the same with background and you will have better support:

```css
.box {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) left,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,blue 49.5%,transparent 50%) right;
  background-size:100% 100%,0% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  height:150px;
}

.box:hover {
  background-size:80.1% 100%,20% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Transition property need set to class if you want to use it for pseudo class

```css
.mydiv {
  background: red;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.mydiv:hover {
   background: blue;
   clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 80% 100%, 0% 100%);
 }
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
  Hello world
</div>
```

Comment: the issue is not the transition, it can be set on :hover and it will work fine, you will simply don't have a transition when unhover.

Comment: @TemaniAfif if you start my code snippet, you will see that transition is active on unhover too.

Comment: That's what I said, moving the transition property will simply add the transtion on unhover but the main issue with the code isn't with the transition but the value of clip-path